# What is the usage idiom of cmake cache for improving performance

Tags: cmake

Is this the right idiom to discover a variable value and cache it only if it hasn't been cached already? Using the path type is just for example purposes.

```
IF(NOT $CACHE{PATH_CACHED})
  #discover the PATH_CACHED value and store it in PATH_NORMAL
  SET(PATH_CACHED ${PATH_NORMAL} CACHE FILEPATH "My path")
ENDIF(NOT $CACHE{PATH_CACHED})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `if (NOT DEFINED)`, like so:

```
if (NOT DEFINED PATH_CACHED)
    # do something expensive to compute PATH_CACHED as a normal
    # variable
endif ()

set(PATH_CACHED "${PATH_CACHED}"
    CACHE FILEPATH "My path")
```

Two main points here:

1. Using `if (NOT DEFINED X)` is a more precise check than `if (NOT X)` since someone might want to set `X` to empty.
2. Unconditionally setting `PATH_CACHED` to the computed normal variable has more consistent behavior across a range of CMake versions and also preserves the behavior of adjusting a path relative to the process working directory when an untyped cache variable (set on the command line as `-DPATH_CACHED=foo`) gets a type of `PATH` or `FILEPATH`. See the docs here: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#cmdoption-cmake-D

Also there hasn't been any need to use all-caps command names or to repeat the condition in `endif()` for almost twenty years.